ROUND() for decimal places with ZEROs
When I attending a SQL challenge, I am asked to write a query to find average ticket price which is rounded off to 2 decimal places. I got answer as 42.5,55.But the test case is not passed because the answer should be as 42.50,55.00.I used ROUND() ,what is the reason? What I needed to be write there
I need a SQL query for Oracle database, which output as
ticket_price
42.50
55.00
but i am getting as
ticket_price
42.5
55
Even though I used ROUND()

welcome to [so] - please [edit] your question and add how you are using round() - in other words, show us what you are doing so we can spot the missing pieces to get you where you need to be

Can you please give us some  rows of sample data and expected output.

ROUND returns a NUMBER data-type and 42.5 and 42.50 have exactly the same value so are equal and if you just display a number then it will only display the significant digits (and trailing zeroes are not significant when considering value).
What the question was asking you to do was to display the number to a specific precision (which is not quite the same as just rounding to a value) and, for that, you can use TO_CHAR and include the trailing zeroes in the format model:
SELECT TO_CHAR(average_ticket_price, 'FM99990D00') AS average_ticket_price
FROM   table_name;

(Note: TO_CHAR will automatically round the number to the precision set by the format model so you do not need to round first.)
Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (average_ticket_price) AS
SELECT 33.333333 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 66.666666 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 42.5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 55 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



AVERAGE_TICKET_PRICE




33.33


66.67


42.50


55.00



fiddle
